# How to import chromium content shell build into Android Studio?

Tags: android, browser, java-native-interface, chromium

I'm trying to build Chromium open source browser for Android. I have followed steps given here:

Visit: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_build_instructions.md

I followed the following steps to create a gradle build of the content shell 
Visit: https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/docs/android_studio.md

When I import and try to run the code it gives me the following error

**../../../../../../../../../../base/android/java/src/org/chromium/base/memory/MemoryPressureMonitor.java

error: cannot find symbol method metafactory(Lookup,String,MethodType,MethodType,MethodHandle,MethodType)**

Please help me getting over this problem.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue... Did you solve this?